# Eslint --init appears to be hanging

Tags: eslint

Running the command ***eslint --init*** in a CMD shell on Windows 10.

After entering the above command, then no questions appear.

I installed using ***npm install -g eslint*** . This was version v2.4.0. Entering the command eslint -v returned the version.

Additional information.

If I run the command eslint on a simple js file, I am getting this back.

D:\Dropbox\Projects\myLibraryNodeV2>eslint server.js
undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new IgnoredPaths (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eslint\lib\ignored-paths.js:152:17)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnFiles (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli-engine.js:494:28)
    at Object.cli.execute (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eslint\lib\cli.js:179:95)
    at Object. (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eslint\bin\eslint.js:79:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)

D:\Dropbox\Projects\myLibraryNodeV2>eslint -v
v2.4.0

Comment: Whats the node version?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. eslint wasn't installing properly. It appeared on this machine there were two version of node installed X86 and x64, the x86 version was very old. So when I was running the npm install from within windows CMD, it was running the old x86. When I realised this, I ran the NPM install from within the Node command prompt.